# Rails Whenever gem and cron job not working on development environment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, cron, whenever

so this is like my first time doing a cron job, and also using a whenever gem.

this is what's in my schedule.rb

```
set :environment, :development

every 1.minute do
   command  "rails runner /home/ec2-user/projectA/scripts/download.rb"
end
```

It's running a script where it download's a file and does a few more other thing.
However, for some reason , the job is not running ? nothing is happening, the results are not returning. why is that?

UPDATE#############

i checked my cron log file, and it seems that it was running the script every minute as intended. however my results of the script is not producing as i would to run it manually.. why is that?

Comment: A few things to check: Do you have `cron` installed? (Run: `$ crontab -l` to "list" the installed cronjobs). Did you run the command (`$ whenever --update-crontab`) to install the task in your `schedule.rb` into the cron tab?

Comment: Yes both are in check

Comment: I'm pretty sure its not the whenever gem's fault now, but its the cron job not working on my development env